# how to design a step for Spring batch that only do a read task

Tags: java, spring, spring-batch

My batch goes like Step1 Step2 and Step3( should be called if step2 is success).

I need to do a count check using sql like select count(*) from table where condition = ? in step2.
Fail if count is 0;

As i have just a Read chunk and a Process check NOT a writer. but spring does not allow it. Should I try with tasklet ? 
But tasklet is not a Reader ... Suggestion ?

Comment: Being new to spring batch i posted this question. its no more needed.

Answer (score 0):

You could use the Dummy Item writer or roll out you own do nothing writer
http://docs.spring.io/spring-batch/trunk/apidocs/org/springframework/batch/sample/support/DummyItemWriter.html

Answer (score 0):

Here optimal solution can be - avoid using three steps - like Step1 Step2 and Step3.

You can use only two steps . Step1 and Step2 .

In step1 - add a listener - Step listener over it.

In its StepListener - implementation - u can fetch the count and then you can decide if you want the step 2 to start or not.

Here in afterStep mothod  - you can use code like below to get the count --

```
    Connection conn = null;
    PreparedStatement pstmt= null;

    try {


    DataSource dataSource = (DataSource) Main.APP_CONTEXT
            .getBean("dataSource");

     conn = dataSource.getConnection();
     pstmt = conn.prepareStatement(" your SQL query to insert ");
 pstmtMstr.executeQuery();




    } catch (Exception e) {

    }finally{

        if(pstmt!=null){
            pstmt.close();
        }if(conn!=null){
            conn.close();
        }


    }
```

In your Main class - load your application context in a static variable - APP_CONTEXT and use it here.

If you are not using XML based approach then you can use autowire to get the datasource.